# Change of eigenvalues of a matrix when pre- and post multiplied by a diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. Moreover, assume $D$ is an $n \times n$ diagonal matrix with positive diagonals. What is the relation between the eigenvalues of $A$ and eigenvalues of $B:=DAD$? In other words, how do the eigenvalues of the matrix $A$ change when it is pre and post multiplied by a diagonal matrix? Do $A$ and $B$ have the same inertia?
We can assume that $A$ is diagonalizable if necessary.

Any comment/response is greatly appreciated.

Comment: $A$ and $B$ are congruent (since $D=D^T$) so they do have the same inertia

Comment: Thanks for the comment. How about the location of eigenvalues. Is there any result on how the eigenvalues of $A$ would move?

Comment: Is $A$ symmetric?

Comment: Not necessarily.

Comment: Either way there are some inequalities, but you won’t get the exact new eigenvalues without knowing more about $A$.

Comment: I appreciate it if you give me some ideas how I can get those inequalities. They would be very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Bhatia's *Matrix Analysis* is usually a good reference for these purposes, but I'm having trouble finding inequalities that would apply to your specific situation.  If you were content to consider the singular values rather than eigenvalues, then we could note that $DAD$ is similar to $D^2 A$, and that
$$
\prod_{j=1}^k \sigma_j(D^2A) \leq \prod_{j=1}^k \sigma_j(D^2) \prod_{j=1}^k \sigma_j(A)
$$
The singular values of $D^2$, since $D^2$ is diagonal with positive diagonals, are just those values on the diagonal.

Comment: You can find more inequalities along these lines in section III.4 of Bhatia's text (Lidskii's theorems)

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thanks a lot! That's a nice reference.

Answer (score 0):

Does congruence preserve inertia only for symmetric $A$? I have a similar problem with blocked $A = \begin{bmatrix}L& B\\B& L\end{bmatrix}$ and $D = \begin{bmatrix}D_1& \\& D_2\end{bmatrix}$; where $L$ is symmetric but $B$ is not symmetric. I know $A$ has all nonnegative eigenvalues, does that hold for $DAD$?